# Given there are exactly 7 successes 3 minutes, what is the probability that they all came in the last minute?

Tags: probability, statistics, exponential-distribution

Suppose that phone calls arrive at a switchboard according to a Poisson Process at a rate of 2 per minute. Given there are exactly 7 calls in 3 minutes, what is the probability that they all came in the last minute?

My idea is that this is similar to distinct balls in distinct buckets. So answer is 1/(3^7) = 0.0457%

Comment: I think you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. Conditioning a Poisson process on the number $n$ of events in a given time period yields $n$ events independently uniformly distributed over that time period, so each call independently has probability $\frac13$ of having arrived in the last minute.

Comment: So if it was asked only 4 calls came in the last minute, how would it be?

Comment: @DomJo: Well, the principle is the same that you already applied for $7$ calls: $\left(\frac13\right)^4$. Why would it be any different for $4$ than for $7$ calls?

Comment: I meant out of 7, only 4 came in the last minute

Comment: @DomJo: I see. Since all $7$ calls are independently uniformly distributed, it's a binomial distribution with $p=\frac13$, in which the probability for $4$ successes is $\binom74\left(\frac13\right)^4\left(1-\frac13\right)^3$.